# Changing a frame range in blender file via command line

Tags: python, command-line

For farm rendering, I need to copy my blend file multiple times and change the frame FROM and TO in each of them via script.

I try to create the following python file (with 123 as example)

MyFile.py:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = 123
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```

And try then with macos command line:

> /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender -P MyFile.py -b
> MyBlendFile.blend

However it does not save the change. Any idea if it's possible to change the frame range in a blend file using command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, it was about the order of arguments in the command line. I used -P (python script) first and then -b (blender file), when the opposite had to be done